# Is there any difference between the definitions int arr; and int arr[1];

Tags: c, memory-management, definition

I just wanted to know that, Is there any difference between the definitions `int arr;` and `int arr[1];` (except the accessing, i know we need to access as `arr` and `arr[0]`). According to my knowledge both are allocating same size of memory (`sizeof(int)`). Is there any other details about these allocations.

Comment: The type of `arr` is different in each case.

Comment: The only thing same about the two is that they need the same amount of memory. Everything else is different. They are different types, they need to be used differently.

Comment: I suppose that when `arr[1]` is a local variable it will always be allocated on stack, it can't be allocated in a register. I do not see  other difference in space allocation at the moment.

Comment: @Marian Thanks for comment. this is what i'm expecting.

Comment: @Marian: An array can be defined with the `register` keyword; you just can't index it (because you can't take its address).

Comment: Side note - you could access `arr[0]` as `*arr` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr;
```

Here `arr` is a variable of type int.sizeof(arr) will return size of the integer.

```
int arr[1];
```

Here `arr` is a array of type int which can hold elements of type int. In this case it can hold only one integer element.sizeof(arr[0]) will return size of first element of the array which is an integer.

For both the local variable and array the memory is allocated on stack.

Answer (score 0):

i think `int arr[1]` allocate more memory than `int arr`
the fact that `int arr[1]` create a pointer on the first element. So you have the `arr` pointer, that is a registred value of `&arr[0]` and the arr[0] value.

Also you can access arr[0] directly by `*arr`